# Magento - products pr page issue

Tags: magento, grid, categories

Im setting up a Magento community installation, and im having a weird issue with the settings for showing a particular amounts of products pr page.

Even though i have over 50 products in a category, the first page in the category displays "show 1-9 of total 9 products". So on the first page, the system thinks i have 9 products in total. At the same time, it still show pagination for 4 pages, and if i select "show all products", its show all 50.

So, the problem is that it always think the total amount of products is what the value in "products pr page is set to".

I want it to say: showing 1-9 of total 50 products, not "showing 1-9 of total 9, which really is 50 if you just click next":/

Hope i made myself understood.. Thanks for feedback on this..

Answer (score 0):

Try running a reindex on Category Products.
(admin->system->index management)